# Can't update object in outer scope while handling promise from cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with updating an object in outer scope in combination with handling a promise. I'm working with a Firestore database, where I get my data from. Hence Firestore returns promises I've to deal with them.

### The problem

After some hours of research I could reproduce my problem. I now know how to get the results, but I don't know why I get them. I need some support for explanation regarding the behaviour of JS.
In the three examples below I created code snippets which update an object using three different environments. The way I update the object however is always the same. But for every example I get a different result.

### Three different code snippets for updating an object

The following snippet is always the same and invokes one of the functions below:

```js
(() => {
  firestoreCollection
    .doc('someDoc')
    .get()
    .then((bas) => {
      //Not using bas here in the example
      const result = exampleFunction1(par1);
      console.log('1.', result);
      return result;
    })
    .then((fou) => {
      console.log('2.', fou);
    })
    .catch(err => {console.log(err.message)})
})()
```

#### Example 1 (without promise):

```js
const someObject = {}
function exampleFunction1(arg) {
    const someConstant = ['someString1', 'someString2'];
    const anotherConstant = 'anotherSring';
    someConstant.forEach((name, index) => {
      someObject[name].foo = {bar1: anotherConstant[index], bar2: anotherConstant[index]};
    })
    console.log('3.', someObject);
    return someObject //That's useless I guess, because the object in outer scope is updated.
                      //So I don't *have to* return this
  }
```

This prints the following to the console:

```sh
3. { someString1: { foo: 'anotherSring1' }, someString2: { foo: 'anotherSring1' } }
1. { someString1: { foo: 'anotherSring1' }, someString2: { foo: 'anotherSring1' } }
2. { someString1: { foo: 'anotherSring1' }, someString2: { foo: 'anotherSring1' } }
```

#### Example 2 (with promise created by myself):

```js
const someObject = {}
function exampleFunction2(arg) {
    const someConstant = ['someString1', 'someString2'];
    const anotherConstant = ['anotherSring1', 'anotherSring2'];
    someConstant.forEach((name, index) => {
      new Promise((res, rej) => {
        console.log('inside promise', someObject);
        res();
      }).then(whatever => {
        someObject[name]. foo = {bar1: anotherConstant[index], bar2: anotherConstant[index]};
        return 'ok' //Only returning something because one should do
      }).catch(err => {console.log(err.message);})
    })
    console.log('3.', someObject);
    return someObject //That's useless I guess, because the object in outer scope is updated.
                      //So I don't *have to* return this
  }
```

This prints the following to the console:

```sh
3. {  }
1. {  }
2. { someString1: { foo: 'anotherSring1' }, someString2: { foo: 'anotherSring1' } }
```

#### Example 3 (with promise/then from firestore):

```js
const someObject = {}
function exampleFunction3(arg) {
    const someConstant = ['someString1', 'someString2'];
    const anotherConstant = ['anotherSring1', 'anotherSring2'];
    someConstant.forEach((name, index) => {
      firestoreCollection //This is a collection reference from firestore
        .doc('someDoc')
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          someObject[name].foo = {bar1: anotherConstant[index], bar2: anotherConstant[index]};
          return 'ok' //Only returning something because one should do
        })
        .catch(err => {console.log(err.message);})
    })
    console.log('3.', someObject);
    return someObject //That's useless I guess, because the object in outer scope is updated.
                      //So I don't *have to* return this
  }
```

This prints the following to the console:

```sh
3. {  }
1. {  }
2. {  }
```

### My Question

Why do I get three different results for the three approaches? It seems to be something with the promises. The example 3 is the one I have to get running.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650290/firestore-cloud-function-value-of-external-variable-not-recognized-in-then) question didn't help me to solve my problem.

Comment: I got a step further. If I comment `res();` in example 2, I get the same result as of example 3. So, I guess that the code in the `.then()` method needs something to tell it to finish. Like `res();`. But don't know how, yet.

Comment: Suddenly I find the right websites and I guess my problem is solved. [This](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) medium article helped me to understand what happens while execution and what not. Credits to Sebastien Chopin. When I'm absolutely certain regarding the behaviour I will create an answer for it. But an answer from someone who is more experienced is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some `async` and `await`s in your functions. If an arrow function is going to have an asynchronous task inside of it, it needs an `async` before the parameters:

```
someConstant.forEach(async (name, index) => {
      return await firestoreCollection
        .doc('someDoc')
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          ...
        })
        .catch(err => {
          ...
        })
    })
```

[`get` is an asynchronous function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get), so you have to wait for (`await`) a result to come back from the database to actually *use* the data there. Right now it is `get()`ting the data, but you're not waiting for it so it doesn't populate `someObject` like you expect it to.

I'd recommend the [MDN async documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for further reference.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your approach but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. But that's my fault. I didn't mention, that *firestoreCollection* isn't a pending promise. It's already resolved. At least, that's what the console shows me. My guess is, that the code in the .then() method is pushed to end of all execution, for some reason. In case of Example 3 it can't finish at all. But still researching. Looking forward for the eureka effect.

Comment: After I found more information regarding async functions and promises I've to admit that your answer is almost what I searched for. Hence the main problem is a promise inside a forEach function I would rather wait for an answer that fully explains the behaviour and providing a solution. Nevertheless many thanks.